# Is there a way in Android Studio to show the "All" navigation tab automatically?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, key-bindings

Ctrl+N shows classes, Ctrl+Shift+N files, is there an action which can show the All tab automatically? I like that better for completion.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press double shift as <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> quickly.

It is called *Search everywhere*

Comment: It's also on `numpad+*` and knowing the name of the action I can also bind it to other keys. Thanks!